# tcl error bareword "string" in while loop

Tags: tcl

I'm new at TCL
I have the following if and while loop:

```
cd c:/users/john/desktop
set file1 [ open 1n5u.pdb ]
set file2 [ open alpha.pdb w]
while {$x==0 } {
    set p1 [gets $file1]
    set length1 [string range $line 0 3]
    set length2 [string range $line 14 15]
    set length3 [string index $line 78]
    if {(string equal $length1 "ATOM") && (string equal $length2 "CA")&& (string equal $length3 "C")} {
        puts $file2 $line }
    set x  [ eof $line ]
}
close $file1
close $file2
```

My while loop didn't work correctly; the error is :
invalid bareword "string"
in expression "(string equal $length1 "ATOM"...";
should be "$string" or "{string}" or "string(...)" or ...
.
how can I fix it?

Comment: You're using parenthesis instead of braces. Need the latter to evaluate the command inside.

Comment: Or just use `expr`'s `eq` operator: `$length1 eq "ATOM" && ...`, etc.

Comment: Critical syntax error in your expression: use `[string equal $length1 "ATOM"]`, not `(string equal $length1 "ATOM")`